# Access a model method by Laravel ajax

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I have an ajax call that calls a method from a controller

```
public function getVisitas(Request $request)
{
    $visitas = Visita::where('usuario','=',$request->id)->get();
    return $visitas;
}
```

In my model `Visita`  have the following method

```
public function getDiff()
{
    $fx = $this->fecha; // attribute fecha
    return Carbon::parse($fx)->diffForHumans();
}
```

From ajax in my view I can access all the attributes of the `Visita` class, but I do not know how to access the result of the `getDiff` method

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rename `getDiff` to `getDiffAttribute` and [add the `diff` property to the `$appends` array](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/eloquent-serialization#appending-values-to-json):

```
protected $appends = ['diff'];
```

Then you'll see a new `diff` property in returned JSON.

Comment: Sorry, I need to change the name of the method, it works correctly.