# diffForHumans does not work returns me The separation symbol could not Carbon

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, php-carbon

I have a field in my `MySQL` table `fecha` as datetime, to which I want to apply the appropriate format and then get the difference using `diffForHumans` but it shows me error

> "message": "The separation symbol could not be found\r\nThe separation
>   symbol could not be found\r\nData missing",
>       "exception": "InvalidArgumentException",
>       "file": "C:\laragon\www\appcolegio\vendor\nesbot\carbon\src\Carbon\Carbon.php",
>       "line": 582,

I have this in my class `Visita`

```
public function getFechaAttribute($value)
{

    return Carbon::createFromFormat('d/m/Y H:i:s',strtotime($value))
        ->timezone('America/Lima');
}

public function getDiffAttribute()
{
    $fx = $this->fecha;
    return Carbon::createFromFormat('d/m/Y H:i:s',strtotime($fx))
            ->timezone('America/Lima')
            ->diffForHumans();
}
```

In my view I want to show these two values, on the one hand the current date with the corresponding timezone and on the other the difference with the corresponding timezone

How can I achieve it?  Use Laravel 5.5

Comment: Please check my answer below. If you still want to it manually, please show result of `dd(strtotime($fx))`;

Comment: Ok. What does `dd($this->fech)` show?

Comment: Ok. Put the `dd($value)` in the beginning of `getFechaAttribute`

Comment: What exactly does `dd($value)` show?

Comment: I've updated the answer. You're using the wrong format.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change the format from:

```
d/m/Y H:i:s
```

To:

```
Y-m-d H:i:s
```

And remove the `strtotime()`

Comment: It works to a certain extent. The only thing it does not do is give it the form d/m/YYYY h:m:s to Fecha. remember I want to show two columns in my view

Comment: @DarkFenix create another accessor but not for `fecha`. For example, `public function getFechaStringAttribute` and then use `fechaString` in the view. Or just do `$model->fecha->format($customStringFormat)` in the view.

Comment: It works, but not the format be lost? since I wish d/m/Y or d-m-Y ,  there is no way to show it like that?

Comment: @DarkFenix you can create additional accessors for any format you want like `getFechaYMDAttribute()`.

Comment: @DarkFenix you already know how to create an additional accessor (the `getDiffAttribute`) and I've shown how to append it to JSON in [another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48610964/access-a-model-method-by-laravel-ajax).